# JayData cannot read WCF data service because of CORS

Tags: jquery, cors, wcf-data-services, jaydata

I have created a WCF Data Service and set the followings in my web page:

```
 var mongo = new MyCtx.MyContext({ name: 'oData', oDataServiceHost: 'http://xxxxxxxxx/MongoDataService.svc/', enableJSONP: false });
```

In my WCF Data Service web.config:

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="3600" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, MaxDataServiceVersion" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

When I try to open it, I get the following errors:

```
SEC7118:  http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/MongoDataService.svc//DataTable1 " XMLHttpRequest for [URL] required Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS). 
SEC7119: "XMLHttpRequest for [URL] required CORS preflight."
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network problem 0x80070005, Access denied.
```

My IIS server has the following headers defined:

[image]

What else should I do?

Comment: In my case, I only added <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> and it can work. Maybe you should try to remove others?

Comment: @QianLi I modified it, but nothing happens. It still wants CORS to be enabled. I have full access to the IIS server but can't enable such a tiny thing...

Answer (score 0):

Add in your WCF data service file Global.asax ( if you dont have already ).
Then handle BeginRequest event , and add the code :

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, MERGE" );
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, MaxDataServiceVersion, DataServiceVersion, Authorization");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Then it should work :)